# How to Enable Geo-Replication

Tags: azure-storage

Is it possible to enable the `Geo-Replication` in an already running VM?

How we can make sure that `Geo-Replication` is working?

Is there any other option for securing the Data safe?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable geo replication on your storage account associated with your VM (Azure storage account you used while creating the VM). You can enable this via Service Management REST APIs for [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh264518.aspx) and [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh264516.aspx) Storage Account or via the [Windows Azure Portal](https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://login.windows.net/&wreply=https://login.windows.net/common/wsfederation&wctx=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&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&id=500879&cbcxt=azuManage). Current options for geo replicating data in your storage account are GRS (Geographically Redundant Storage) and RA-GRS (Read-Access Geographically Redundant Storage). For more information on this, please refer to blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/04/introducing-read-access-geo-replicated-storage-ra-grs-for-windows-azure-storage.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean Ge-Replication for a Storage Account. You should be able to enable it from the management portal.

You can optionally enable read from secondary, which will give you read access to the data on the secondary.